# iOS "Cannot Decode" m3u8

Tags: ios, live-streaming, m3u8

I have a live stream that in the past was playable on iOS devices (using the URL for the m3u8 file).  Now, when I try to view the live stream on an iOS device, I get a message that says "Cannot Decode".  I am still able to use this file on Android devices though.  Does anyone have any idea why iOS devices would not be able to play this file?

The live stream is being encoded by Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2 and we are using Adobe Media Server 5.  I followed the steps [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/devguide/WSd391de4d9c7bd609-52e437a812a3725dfa0-8000.2.3.html) to get everything setup initially (when it was working).  Once it stopped working on iOS, I verified that none of the settings had changed.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not support FLASH, so iOS cannot decode a FLV stream, it only support [HLS(HTTP Live Streaming)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You can set the Live Encoder as following

- *Preset*: H.264
- *Video* Format (H.264), click the right spanner, set Profile(Main), Level(3.1), Keyframe Frequency(4 seconds)
- FMS URL: `rtmp://yoursever/livepkgr`    and Stream: `livestream?adbe-live-event=liveevent`

Then, open iDevice Safari and go to `http://yoursever/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.m3u8`,it will be played.
[image]

Comment: I've done all that already (which is why it had been working in the past), I'm linking to the .m3u8 file and that's when I'm getting the Cannot Decode error.  I verified that none of the setting have changed since I first set it up, and they haven't.

Comment: @SarahSmith Sorry, I misunderstood your meaning of the question. So do you mean that it does not work on iOS now without anything changed? Could you provide an URL for testing?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Here's the url: http://167.154.9.33/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.m3u8
I have the stream started, but our cameras aren't on so it'll just be blue.

Comment: @SarahSmith It can be played on my iPhone 4, did you tried on other iDevices?

Comment: I've only tried on an iPhone, but it has the iOS 7 beta on it, so I wonder if that's the issue...